# Meaning of "of something"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

**What is the meaning of "of something" in the highlighted part?**

> James, his sister Sally, and Mark, their BFF (Best Friend Forever)
> were bored. They had played all day but now that it was dark and
> difficult to see, they had nothing to do. They couldn't play soccer
> because they couldn't see the ball. They didn't want to go inside and
> play a game because it was a beautiful springtime night and they liked
> being outside, especially after having to play inside all winter long.
> They just didn't know what to do and it was a little too early for
> them to go home. "I guess I'll just go home," Mark said in a sad
> voice. "Aww come on," replied James. "We still have time for **another
> game of - of something**."

Comment: There are many errors in your transcription of the passage! James suggested another game, but couldn't think which game they might play.

Comment: You can use free online optical character recognition (OCR) services to convert images of text into editable text, which you can then manually edit before posting.

Answer (score -1):

The repetition of 'of' in 'of - of something' indicates hesistancy or uncertainty. James wants to play one more game, but does not know which one, so he just says that they should play another game of 'something'. He probably hopes that the other childen will agree to continue playing, and suggest a game.

> something
> pronoun
>
> an object, situation, quality, or action that is not exactly known or
> stated

[Something (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/something)